# Custom TableViewCell | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cell, uitableview

I'm trying to add to table different content such as images/text.
I've created 2 custom tableViewCells for both types. I have the main array, where it all will be saved (images encode to base64 because of storing in JSON).

```
var content = [String]()
var imgCell: ImageTableViewCell = ImageTableViewCell()
var txtCell: TextTableViewCell = TextTableViewCell()
```

Having two buttons for adding images/text.

```
@IBAction func textAddButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.content.append("text")
    self.articleTableView.reloadData()
}
```

In updating the table i cant understand how to connect array data with custom cells and display it.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    if content[indexPath.row] == "text" {
        return txtCell
    }
    else {
        return imgCell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Here is custom cell.

```
class TextTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textArticle: UITextView!

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize cells like that. Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and depending on the `indexPath` you setup the cell accordingly. If you've created the cells in a Storyboard file make sure to set their identifiers in the storyboard.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView. dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifierForIndexPath(indexPath), forIndexPath:indexPath)
    // set up cell accordingly
}

func identifierForIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> String {
    // for example: (you can set this up according to your needs)
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return "ImageCell" // these must match your identifiers in your storyboard
    }
    return "TextCell"
}
```

Alternatively you can have separate blocks in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for each cell type, and then you would have something like:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! TextTableViewCell
```

Comment: is there any reasons to give them identifiers if i set for each cell a class?

Comment: `UITableView` uses string identifiers to identify cells (e.g. for reuse). If you want to use `UITableView` then you have to use it according to its API.

Comment: okay but the question is in how can i connect data from array and depending on the type, use the needed class and display it in array?

Comment: because in cell class i coded nothing, only textview/imageview

Comment: Look up the content for the row with your array and the index path and set up the cell accordingly.

Google `UITableView` examples or look at the [Apple guides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) if you're still confused.